# Pagination of jsonb elements in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the following format

id: uuid
versionid: uuid
data: jsonb

the sample data can be ('some uuid', 'some other uuid', '{"files": [{"name": "file1"}], "users": [{"age": 18}]}');

How can I query the data to return just a single row of

```
{
    id: "some_uuid",
    versionid: "some_uuid",
    data:{
        "files":[{"name": "name 1"}],
        "users": [{"age": 18}]
    }
}
```

```
enter code here
```

and be able to limit the length of the returned elements in each of the above arrays (files, and users). mainly paginating them. return some now, then some later. some implementation of limit and offset or some array index accessing.

Comment: If the json object is so large it needs paginating, you should probably not be storing it as a single object.

Comment: The current implementation requires me to store it as JSON since it is irregular.